# What's causing this Parsing error? ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Cannot be negative. Parameter name: length

Tags: c#, parsing, unity-game-engine

I have a list of objects and a delete() but it's generating

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Cannot be negative. Parameter name: length 

    private void delete(int a)
    {
        if (currentSelected == -1) return;

        string str = list.IndexOf(list[currentSelected]).ToString();
        Debug.Log("STR: "+str); //returns the correct index
        int id = int.Parse(str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf("\t"))); //Error occurs here
   }
```

Why is id getting a negative value?

Comment: str.IndexOf("\t") returned -1 because it does that when it cannot find the value: "The zero-based index position of value if that character is found, or -1 if it is not."

Comment: Hm I wonder if the \t is getting stripped when I load it in from my .xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IndexOf` will return -1 if the element is not found.

Clearly here there is no tab character in `str`, thus you have a length of -1, throwing the exception.

A quick if check would help here:

```
if (str.Contains('\t'))
{
   ...
}
```